# Dar um loop infinito

Tags: cmd, batch

eu presiso de um comando que faz um loop em taskkill, exemplo:

> Se o processo estiver aberto, será detectado o processo e ativara o taskkill, mas também quero que outros comandos diferentes executem, se você não entendeu, é assim:

> o batch identifica o processo em um loop, e executem outros comandos além do taskkill

só que não achei nada sobre isso.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria algo assim, no caso esse batch verifica a cada 5 segundos se o processo existe e se existir finaliza ele com taskkill e executa mais alguns comandos (comando2, comando3...) que você pode substituir com os comandos que você quiser.

```
@echo off
:Loop
Tasklist |find /i "NomeDoProcesso.exe"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
                       taskkill /im "NomeDoProcesso.exe" /f
                       comando2
                       comando3
                       comando4
                      )
timeout /t 5 
goto :Loop
```